# AutoresizesSubviews не работает

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, view

Вопрос по анимации. 
Допустим, у меня есть View размером 100 на 100, и внутри CAShapeLayer размером 100 на 100, подогнано под  айфон 5, и добавлены концертанты.

Далее
если запустить на 6-м, то размер view станет, например, 200 на 200, 
а сабвью не изменится.

Как быть? `autoresizesSubviews` не помогает.

Comment: @hoppus, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

CALayer не UIView. Попробуй перегрузить `- (void)layoutSubviews` и там установить `myLayer.frame = self.bounds`